# In magento which price or price rule has the highest priority?

Tags: magento-1.7, price, catalog-price-rules, tierprice

Suppose I have set following rules/prices set in Magento for product (all type)

1) Special price

2) Tier Prices

3) Catalog price rules

4) Group prices

Then which price will be having highest priority and which  will be applicable to the product on adding to the cart?

Comment: Go through this, it will give you detailed explanation on price calculations.. http://www.slideshare.net/ivanchepurnyi/hidden-secrets-of-magento-price-rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento takes the minimal value (lowest price) from the following calculated price variations

- Product Price
- Tier Price
- Group Price (CE1.7+)
- Special Price
- Catalog Rule Price

Reference as Marius says above, slide #9 from Ivan Chepurnyi (used to be part of the Magento Core Team so should know the correct answer!)

Comment: You mean to say the price which will be the lowest from these prices will be used?

Answer (score 3):

Magento also give the highest  priority  as follow

1) Catalog price rules

2) Special price

3) Tier Prices

4) Group prices

Comment: @Supravat Is this lowest to highest?

Comment: No. there are highest to lowest order.

Answer (score 0):

Magento takes the minimal value from the following variations: Product Price, Tier Price, Group Price, Special Price, Catalog Rule Price. There is no priority at all. If Product Price is 100 and Catalog Rule Price is 150, Product Price will be used, because this is the minimal value. In Magento 1.9.3.2 I did some scenarios.

**Scenario 1**

- Group Price (NOT LOGGED) = 200
- Special Price = 300
- Result in product page: 200
- Result in category page: 200
- If you add the product to cart the price is 200

**Scenario 2**

- Group Price (NOT LOGGED) = 200
- Tier Price (NOT LOGGED IN, Qty 1) = 100
- Result in product page: 200, Buy 1 for 100 and save 50%
- Result in category page: 200, As low as 100
- If you add the product to cart the price is 100

**Scenario 3**

- Special Price = 300
- Tier Price (NOT LOGGED IN, Qty 1) = 100
- Result in product page: 300, Buy 1 for 100 and save 50%
- Result in category page: 300, As low as 100
- If you add the product to cart the price is 100

**Scenario 4**

- Group Price (NOT LOGGED) = 200
- Special Price = 300
- Tier Price (NOT LOGGED IN, Qty 1) = 100
- Result in product page: 200, Buy 1 for 100 and save 50%
- Result in category page: 200, As low as 100
- If you add the product to cart the price is 100

**Conclusion**:

1) It is very important how you set up your promotions in case you have more than an option to use (see above). You can see a price but it could be different than the one in shopping cart (tier price used).

2) Magento evaluates the lowest value. If you set up above Special Price to 200 and Group Price to 300, Special Price will be used.

Comment: In my opinion Magento users should pay attention using [Group Price], [Special Price] and [Tier Price] in different combinations in Product Information page. An accurate method is using [Catalog Price Rules] for the first two, which allows you controlling the time period for every rule. In this way you can set up priorities for your rules applied to the same product too.